# Bundling with sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I implemented the code here:

http://jockstothecore.com/bundling-with-sitecore-mvc/comment-page-1/#comment-6521

It is working perfectly.

I just have a few questions.

I want to know if there is a performance penalty in the code above since the code is using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters. When does the InitializeGlobalFilters triggered? Is it triggered every time the page loads? Or only once per application starts?

I already search the internet and also tried to find answer in the sitecore SDN but can't find the answer.

Please let me know if this is the right approach or there are better way on doing this.

Thanks,

PNOY2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InitializeGlobalFilters` processor is a part of sitecore `initialize` pipeline.

It is registered in `/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Mvc.config` file.

It means that it is called only once when the applications starts.